# Removing objects from ArrayList in java which are used in other classes

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have an `ArrayList` of instructors in my `School` class. I also have an `Administrator` class which is attached to the `School` class. I would like to randomly remove instructors from the school from within the `Administrator` class. Here is my code:

```
public void instructorMayLeave(){
    Iterator<Instructor> instructorIterator = school.getInstructors().iterator();
    while (instructorIterator.hasNext()){
        Instructor instructor = instructorIterator.next();
        int chanceOfLeaving = random.nextInt(100);
        if(chanceOfLeaving < 20){
            instructorIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

However I don't think that instructors are actually being removed from the School class. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Since we're only seeing a small snippet of code, we cannot test it in the context of your program and can't tell (without guessing) why your program isn't behaving as expected or desired. If you remain stuck and without a solution, consider condensing your code and your problem into the smallest program that compiles and runs for us (not the entire program mind you), that demonstrates your problem for us, but that does nothing else, a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what precisely `getInstructors()` does.

- It may return a copy of the liist of instructors. If so, your code only removes instructors from the copy, not from the school. In this case you need the school to have a `removeInstructor` method or similar for you to call.
- Or `getInstructors()` may return the list of instructors itself. In this case your code will remove instructors from the school’s list (depending on your random numbers, of course).

The former is considered the safe design. In this the school in the end itself can control removal of instructors. In the latter design, a client may keep a reference to the list indefinitely and add and remove instructors at any future time.